# IDA python API set function chunk end

Tags: ida, idapython

I’m trying to set a function chunk end at a certain EA in a function using my Ida python plugin, but I can’t find any API which lets me do just that. set_func_end appear not to work (keeps returning false.).
Basically I’m trying to simulate the action of pressing “E” at a certain EA. Appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import ida_funcs
import ida_auto

funcEa = 0x08054FE1
newEndEa = 0x08054FF7

f = ida_funcs.get_func(funcEa)
f.end_ea = newEndEa
ida_funcs.update_func(f)
ida_funcs.reanalyze_function(f)
ida_auto.auto_wait()
```

In response to your edit, perhaps some basic safety precautions would help, as in:

```
f = ida_funcs.get_func(funcEa)
if f is not None:
    nChunk = ida_funcs.func_contains(f,newEndEa)
    if nChunk >= 0:
        if nChunk > 0:
            f = ida_funcs.getn_fchunk(nChunk)
        f.end_ea = newEndEa
        ida_funcs.update_func(f)
        ida_funcs.reanalyze_function(f)
        ida_auto.auto_wait()
```

Comment: Does'nt seem to work. causes IDA to crash

Comment: The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access.

Comment: Seems like its working on other views, i cant seem to set this line: 
.text:00007FF7179EEDE5                 jnb     short near ptr loc_7FF7179EEE06+5
as function end.

Comment: See edit for a solution with safety checking and which explicitly takes chunking into account.